# XSLT Qn : How to add a tag in XML only if it is not present?

Tags: xml, xslt

New to xlst world, trying to make a simple update in an xml file.

I want to add two different tags `<NODE1 name="name1" value="value1"/>` and `<NODE2 name="name2" value="value2"/>` in my XML file ONLY IF they are not present already within the `MAIN_NODE` respectively.

E.g. if NODE1 is not present inside MAIN_NODE, NODE1 should be inserted inside. If NODE2 is not present, NODE2 should be added. If both are not present, both should be added, and vice-versa.

I tried below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >  
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/"> 
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>  
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="MAIN_NODE">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:text>
            </xsl:text>
            <NODE1 name="name1" value="value1"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>         
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It's working but when I run XSLT subsequently, NODE1 gets added repeatedly. How exactly can I put the condition in this code ? And then repeat the same thing for Node2 such that both can work together through a single XSLT.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It worked like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >  
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/"> 
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>  
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="MAIN_NODE">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:if test="not(./NODE1)">
                <NODE1 name="name1" value="value1"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="not(./NODE2)">
                <NODE2>Node2_string</NODE2>
            </xsl:if>                                      
        </xsl:copy>            
    </xsl:template>         
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks,
Rajiv

Answer (score 0):

Change `<xsl:template match="MAIN_NODE">` to `<xsl:template match="MAIN_NODE[not(NODE1)]">` to only use the template for `MAIN_NODE` elements not having a `NODE1` child element.

Comment: Thanks Martin. A quick follow up qn. 

This seems to work for a single tag, however when I try to repeat the same thing for NODE2 by adding `<xsl:template match="MAIN_NODE[not(NODE2)]` below above code,  NODE1 stops working and only NODE2 gets added. 

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Unless you use modes or features like `xsl:next-match`, any node will only be processed by exactly one template. It is not clear from your current description how your different input samples can look and what you want to add so I am not sure currently which approach might be right if you want to transform `MAIN_NODE` elements where different elements might need to be added. Either ask a new question providing the necessary details or edit your question detailing the different types of elements you expect and the corresponding results you want to output.

Comment: Ok, I just updated the problem description here. Sry it wasn't clear earlier.

Comment: It is still not clear which exact result you want if you have e.g. `<MAIN_NODE><FOO/><NODE2/></MAIN_NODE>` in the input, where do you want to insert the `NODE1` element then, after all content, before the `NODE2`?

Comment: Yes, ideally after all content but before NODE2. If that's complex, I don't mind adding NODE1 completely at the end irrespective of where NODE2 is.